# Java replaceAll wrong output

Tags: java

This doesn't output properly. I've read to use \\ but that gives me another error. any help/alternatives?

```
string = string.replaceAll("a", newAlphabet.substring(0,1));
string = string.replaceAll("b", newAlphabet.substring(1,2));
string = string.replaceAll("c", newAlphabet.substring(2,3));
string = string.replaceAll("d", newAlphabet.substring(3,4));
string = string.replaceAll("e", newAlphabet.substring(4,5));
```

This is just part of the code. I'm trying to change a message so that every letter of the alphabet is changed to another letter. Like a jumped alphabet
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
would change to something like
zmlapqokxswncdejibvhfurtgy

so a = z etc

when I try get the output, half of it is correct and some is just plain wrong, and I don't know why

Comment: Define "doesn't output properly". What's your actual output vs expected output? Or does this not compile?

Comment: Have you checked, what the output of your substrings is? Maybe the error is already there.

Comment: thank you! the substring is wrong. 
    substring(8,9)); gives "e" instead of "i" in the regular alphabet
why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the alternative
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29

```
public String replace(CharSequence target,CharSequence replacement)
```

Comment: The only problem with that is that I don't know what the order of the new alphabet will be. the program does that for me, thats why I was using substrings

Comment: What about this one? This looks great
http://omegadelta.net/2010/03/03/simple-java-replaceall-for-string-literals-i-e-no-regex/

String myString = “foo[]bar”;
myString = myString.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(“foo[]“), Matcher.quoteReplacement(“bar$”));
System.out.println(myString);

Answer (score 0):

Well... The problem with your code is that after you change a letter "a" to letter "z" for example you still change all letters "z" after that to another letter, even the letters that are already a result of transformation.

Comment: @user3673571, Go over all letters one by one and concatenate the transformed letters into a StringBuilder

Answer (score 0):

If your text has only ASCII chars with value < 128 (or 256), i would go for mapping array:

```
String original    = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
String replacement = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba";

int[] translate = new int[128];
for(int i = 0; i<128; i++) {
    translate[i] = i; //default = not change
}

for(int i = 0; i<original.length(); i++) {
    translate[original.charAt(i)] = replacement.charAt(i);
}

String toTranslate = "Hello world!";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 0; i<toTranslate.length(); i++) {
    sb.append((char) translate[toTranslate.charAt(i)]);
}

String result = sb.toString();

System.out.println(result); //prints: Hvool dliow!
```

Threre are ofc more soffisticated ways to create the `translate` array, but i hope this will do as an example.